# ionic 2 loading TypeError: n.apply is not a function

Tags: ionic2

I got this error when using ionic 2 loading Component

> error_handler.js:54 EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError:
>   n.apply is not a function TypeError: n.apply is not a function

My ts Code

```
constructor(public http: Http,public loadingCtrl: LoadingController){
    this.loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: "Please wait...",
      dismissOnPageChange: false,
      duration: 3000,
    });
}
ionViewDidLoad()
    {

        let url = this.shareServices.URL+'get_nonce/?controller=user&method=register';
        // let body = '?controller=user&method=register';
        let body = {
            controller : 'user',
            method : 'register',
        }
        let headers = new Headers({
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        });

        let options = new RequestOptions({
            headers: headers,
        });

        this.loader.present().then(
            this.http.post(url, body, options).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
                nonce => {
                    this.nonceResp = nonce;
                    this.loader.dismissAll();
                    // console.log(this.nonceResp.nonce);
                },
                err => {
                    console.log(err);
                    let toast = this.toastCtrl.create({
                        message: 'Error Loading Nonce',
                        duration: 3000
                    });
                    toast.present();
                    this.navCtrl.push(LoginPage);
                }
            )
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the present() method return a promise?
In the [official docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/loading/LoadingController/) the return of present() is never used

You can rewrite it to

```
this.loader.present()
this.http.post(url, body, options)
```

as a synchronous code.